# Tag <TEMPLATE> do HTML para repetições de blocos de código

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Em um documento **.PHP** tenho um trecho de **.HTML** com mais de **20 DIV** praticamente idênticas (vide abaixo o código).

Queria uma forma de declarar uma **DIV "repeteco"** apenas uma vez e onde necessário fosse repetí-la ao longo do documento, fizesse apenas sua referência passando por parâmetros o que a diferencia das "irmãs". Isso reduziria muito o código e facilitaria sua manutenção.

Há algo melhor ou mais apropriado que a **tag TEMPLATE do HTML** para isso? 
Se não, como faria? Obrigada antecipadamente....

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Nome de produto</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Nome" required maxlength="30" name="prod-name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label>Modelo</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Modelo" required maxlength="30" name="prod-model">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label>Marca</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Marca" required maxlength="30" name="prod-marca">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label>Unidades disponíveis</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Unidades" required maxlength="20" pattern="[0-9]{1,20}" name="prod-stock">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) para armazenar um trecho em uma variável. Com ele você poderá salvar múltiplas linhas de maneira fácil.

Basta utilizar:

```
<<<[IDENTIFICADOR]
Texto
Aqui
[IDENTIFICADOR];
```

Para utilizar *label* e *placeholder* customizados, basta envolver o código acima em uma função e utilizar as variáveis (usadas como parâmetros) para customizar esses valores.

**Exemplo:**

```
function buildCodeHtml($name, $model, $marca, $stock) {
    $html = <<<HTML
    <div class="form-group">
       <label>$name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="$name" required maxlength="30" name="prod-name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label>$model</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="$model" required maxlength="30" name="prod-model">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label>$marca</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="$marca" required maxlength="30" name="prod-marca">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label>$stock</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="$stock" required maxlength="20" pattern="[0-9]{1,20}" name="prod-stock">
    </div>
HTML;

    return $html;
}

/* Imprime */
echo buildCodeHtml("Nome 2", "Modelo 2", "Marca 2", 123456);
echo buildCodeHtml("Nome 3", "Modelo 3", "Marca 3", 1);
```

<sup>*Demonstração: https://ideone.com/mHpoEA*</sup>

**Alternativa robusta:**

Com essa alternativa você consegue ter mais autonomia na edição dos campos (*label*, *placeholder* e *name*), porém o código fica maior.

Nesta opção, fiz uma modificação básica, ao invés de informar o nome do campo e *placeholder* de forma idêntica, resolvi passar essas informações como *array*, assim você tem mais liberdade.

```
function buildCodeHtml($name, $model, $marca, $stock) {
    $html = <<<HTML

    <div class="form-group">
       <label>{$name['label']}</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="{$name['placeholder']}" required maxlength="30" name="{$name['name']}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label>{$model['label']}</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="{$model['placeholder']}" required maxlength="30" name="{$model['name']}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label>{$marca['label']}</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="{$marca['placeholder']}" required maxlength="30" name="{$marca['name']}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label>{$stock['label']}</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="{$stock['placeholder']}" required maxlength="20" pattern="[0-9]{1,20}" name="{$stock['name']}">
    </div>
HTML;

    return $html;
}

/* Imprime */
echo buildCodeHtml([
    "name"        => "name2",
    "label"       => "Label Nome - 2",
    "placeholder" => "Placeholder Nome - 2",
], [
    "name"        => "model2",
    "label"       => "Label Model - 2",
    "placeholder" => "Placeholder Model - 2",
], [
    "name"        => "marca2",
    "label"       => "Label Marca - 2",
    "placeholder" => "Placeholder Marca - 2",
], [
    "name"        => "stock2",
    "label"       => "Label Stock - 2",
    "placeholder" => "Placeholder Stock - 2",
]);
```

<sup>*Demonstração: https://ideone.com/tLreO9*</sup>

> Caso você não queira trabalhar aplicando o HTML via *JavaScript*, é uma boa forma.

---

No caso da tag `template`, você precisa adicionar uma função em *JavaScript* para adicionar o código em determinado lugar em seu documento HTML, pode parecer complicado, mas é bastante simples.

**Exemplo:**

```js
/* Captura e armazena o conteúdo do template na variável */
const template = document.querySelector("#meu-template");

/* Adiciona evento de clique no Botão */
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", _ => {

  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  
    /* Clona o template. Isso fará com que possa inclui-lo no documento inúmeras vezes */
    let fragment = document.importNode(template.content, true);
  
    /* Adiciona o fragmento na div #codigo */
    document.querySelector("#codigo").appendChild( fragment )
  }

});
```

```html
<template id="meu-template">
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Nome de produto</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Nome" required maxlength="30" name="prod-name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label>Modelo</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Modelo" required maxlength="30" name="prod-model">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label>Marca</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Marca" required maxlength="30" name="prod-marca">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label>Unidades disponíveis</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Unidades" required maxlength="20" pattern="[0-9]{1,20}" name="prod-stock">
</div>

<hr />
</template>

<div id="codigo"></div>

<button>Adicionar código</button>
```

Comment: Excelente, @Valdeir Psr, até para mim que sou uma novata, consegui compreender bem, vc tem muito domínio. 

Confesso que o HEREDOC me foi mais interessante. 
Via criação do código Javascript (pelo recurso TEMPLATE), a depender do que vc precisa, se o foco for redução de linhas, acaba saíndo 6 por meia-dúzia, concorda?

Comment: Como poderia mudar via HEREDOC (ou não) o LABEL, PLACEHOLDER e NAME de cada DIV?

Comment: @MayaFiuza Atualizei meu exemplo. Utilizei uma função (com alguns parâmetros), dessa forma você consegue customizar os valores toda vez que imprimir o conteúdo.

Comment: Muito obrigada, @Valdeir Psr! Sensacional!!!! :^)